# Jenkins job [ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:jar must be a valid version

Tags: maven, jenkins, pom.xml

When Jenkins job executes the Maven source code following error displays in the console and job failed.Since the project has so many modules.I can't modify the pom.xml files to fix the error by hard coding the version.Somehow I want to solve the error from the Jenkins side by adding some sort of configuration.

```
 [ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:jar must be a valid version but is '${lucene.version}'. @ org.helloproject.search:customer-impl:[unknown-version], /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/HelloProject/search/customer-impl/impl/pom.xml, line 182, column 16
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
    [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
    [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
    Build step 'Invoke top-level Maven targets' marked build as failure
    Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Properties are the usual way to avoid hard coding dependencies.

```
<project>
    <properties>
        <!-- Override this value: -Dlucene.version=6.6.0 -->
        <lucene.version>OVERRIDE_ME</lucene.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
            <artifactId>lucene-core</artifactId>
            <version>${lucene.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

And then run it by `mvn clean install -Dlucene.version=6.6.0`.

However based on your error log I assume it is already done in your project so just try to run it with `-Dlucene.version=6.6.0` in Jenkins.

Comment: I want to add Jenkins Goals to above command.I added                         **clean
install
package
-D**  but it didnt work

Comment: Have you add `mvn clean install -Dlucene.version=6.6.0`?

Comment: command **clean install -Dlucene.version=6.6.0** in Jenkins resolved the error.